# Which Distribution functions with increasing hazard rate has x(1-F(x)) tending to 0 when x tends to infinity?

Tags: distributions, survival, bounds, hazard

Let $F(x)$ be a cumulated distribution function and $f(x)$ the probability density function with an increasing failure rate (IFR or hazard rate), ie $h(z)=f(x)/(1-F(x))$  is increasing. Which distribution functions with an IFR enjoy the following property?
$$
\lim_{x->\infty}x( 1 - F(x)) = 0
$$
For example, the Normal Distribution has this property. Might the Gamma ($\alpha>1$), Weibull ($\lambda>1, \beta>1$) and other IFR distributions have also this property?

Comment: Well, for a _constant_ hazard rate, $1-F(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$ and so $x(1-F(x)) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ and so I would expect that the result holds for all distributions with increasing failure rate (IFR).

Comment: I also "expect" all such distributions to enjoy that property. However, I'd much prefer that it were proven.

Answer (score 1):

A different way to write it down. Using $S(x) = 1-F(x)$ to simplify notation.

We have $$\frac{\text{d} \log S(x)} {\text{d} x} =  -\frac{f(x)}{S(x)}=-h(x)$$

And consequently (by integrating both sides) $$S(x) = S(0) \cdot e^{-\int_0^x h(y) dy} \leq S(0) e^{-h(0) x}$$

Where the [inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities) is due to the condition that $h$ is an increasing function such that $h(y)\geq h(0)$ for every $y>0$.

It follows that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} xS(x) \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^{h(0) x}} =  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{h(0) e^{h(0) x}} =0$$

Where the last follows from l'Hospital's rule.

Also note that the same reasoning with l'Hospital's rule can be used to state more directly and generally

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} xS(x) =  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{1/S(x)} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{h(x) /S(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{S(x)}{h(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{h^2(x)}$$

Or applying another time

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{S(x)}{h(x)} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{S^2(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \frac{1}{S(x)}\right]^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is due to the work by Barlow and Proschan in their book on the Mathematical Theory of Reliability (1987) on page 26 where they say that because the expoentnial distribution constant failure rate is the boundary distribution between IFR and DFR (for decreasing) distributions, it provides natural bounds on $\overline{F}(x)$. $\overline{F}(x)$ crosses the function $\exp^{-\alpha x}$ at most once for $\alpha>0$ unless they coincide identically. Let $F$ have mean $\mu_1$, then $\overline{F}(x)$ must cross $\exp^{-t/\mu_1}$ exactly once, and the crossing is necessarily from above. This observation tells us that $\overline{F}(x)$ tails off exponentially fast.
$$
 \lim_{x\to +\infty}x \overline{F}(x)\leq \lim_{x\to +\infty}x \exp^{-\alpha x} = 0, 
\forall \alpha >0,
$$
So the answer to the question is that all distributions with IFR satisfy the above limit.
ending the proof.